# Json data through POSTMAN rest client in chrome

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, arraylist

I am trying to test the backend service through postman rest client with json data and POST method.

First 2 parameters are arraylist and rest all are either String or Integer
The data i am passing is below:

```
{
 "watchUsers":["user1"],
 "msgUsers":["user2"],
 "status":1,
 "sendTime":319876,
 "compId":"turbo",
 "workId":"ts",
 "startId":"engine",
 "endId":"restore",
 "msg":"Completed Successfully"
}
```

my controller to accept this as below:

```
public WatchDTO add(@RequestBody ArrayList<String> watchUsers,@RequestBody ArrayList<String> msgUsers, Integer status, Integer sendTime, String compId, String workId, String startId, String endId, String msg){
.....
}
```

After submitting i am getting the below error:
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4c352e08; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@4c352e08; line: 1, column: 1]

Any idea how to pass the array & other params.

Comment: Provide a DTO and retrieve the `watchUsers` field.

Answer (score 0):

Define a java bean as follows -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserStat {
    ArrayList<String> watchUsers;
    ArrayList<String> msgUsers;
    int status;
    int sendTime;
    String compId;
    String workId;
    String startId;
    String endId;
    String msg;

    public ArrayList<String> getWatchUsers() {
        return watchUsers;
    }

    public void setWatchUsers(ArrayList<String> watchUsers) {
        this.watchUsers = watchUsers;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMsgUsers() {
        return msgUsers;
    }

    public void setMsgUsers(ArrayList<String> msgUsers) {
        this.msgUsers = msgUsers;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getSendTime() {
        return sendTime;
    }

    public void setSendTime(int sendTime) {
        this.sendTime = sendTime;
    }

    public String getCompId() {
        return compId;
    }

    public void setCompId(String compId) {
        this.compId = compId;
    }

    public String getWorkId() {
        return workId;
    }

    public void setWorkId(String workId) {
        this.workId = workId;
    }

    public String getStartId() {
        return startId;
    }

    public void setStartId(String startId) {
        this.startId = startId;
    }

    public String getEndId() {
        return endId;
    }

    public void setEndId(String endId) {
        this.endId = endId;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

}
```

modify the method inside controller as follows -

public WatchDTO add(@RequestBody UserStat userStat){

}

This should work